# Integration from SFDC to Zuora

Tags: integration, zuora

I don't have knowledge of the integration side in SFDC. I got a new requirement where I have to create a subscription in Zuora based on the data in SFDC. It means I have to send information from SFDC to Zuora. I don't have any idea how to do this.

I am thinking to go for consuming WSDL, I don't know is it possible or I had to go with creating a web service.

Please give me suggestions to go. Please provide me details if anyone had experience with SFDC to Zuora integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of things you could create a callout from Salesforce to Zuora ([Zuora documentation here](https://knowledgecenter.zuora.com/BC_Developers/REST_API)). You could have it calling the Zuora REST Api and schedule the class to run every 10 minutes or so to actually get the information from Zuora.

I have never done anything in Zuora but if there is a way to make a call to Salesforce from Zuora and actually send the data you could create a REST endpoint in Salesforce where you can send the data to.

The Salesforce documentation on this is here: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_REST_APIs_using_Apex_REST